# How to add class in ko template in magento2

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2

I want to add class in ko template

**In js:**

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'mage/translate',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data'
    ], function ($, ko, Component, _, $t, storage, urlBuilder, customer, quote, checkoutData) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            errorMessage: ko.observable(false),
            showElement: ko.observable(),

            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                this.showElement = this.resolveInitialVisibility();
                return this;
            },

            resolveInitialVisibility: function () {
                if (checkoutData.getInputFieldEmailValue() !== '') {
                    return checkoutData.getInputFieldEmailValue() === checkoutData.getCheckedEmailValue();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

I need to add **disable** class for `<div class="col-md-12 pdl0">` if the showElement returns true.

How to do that

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 pdl0" data-bind="css: {'disable': showElement} ">
```

or like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 pdl0" data-bind="css: showElement ? 'disable' : ''">
```